# Where is the event object for external file event handlers?

Tags: events, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

In the [Adobe InDesign CS6 Scripting Guide: JavaScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html) ([link to pdf](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf)), in Chapter 8: Events on page 136 it says,

> `eventListeners` that use handler functions defined inside the script
>   (rather than in an external file) must use `#targetengine "session"`.
>   If the script is run using `#targetengine "main"` (the default), the
>   function is not available when the event occurs, and the script
>   generates an error.

The error looks like this:

> The requested action could not be completed because the object no
>   longer exists.

Using a `#targetengine` is not an option for my script, so I'm stuck with using an external file reference for the event handler.

My problem is this: how do I access the event object in the external file event handler? I've tried `app.scriptArgs.get("event")` and checking `typeof event` to no avail. My event handler is useless without knowing the target of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is available in the local scope through the `evt` variable.

As an example, place these two files in the same folder:

*activateEventHandler.jsx*

```js
var parentFolder = (new File($.fileName)).parent;
var eventHandlerFile = new File(parentFolder.fsName + "/onEvent.jsx");
var eventListener = app.addEventListener("afterNew", eventHandlerFile);
app.documents.add();
eventListener.remove();
```

*onEvent.jsx*

```js
alert("Event '" + evt.eventType + "' with target " + evt.target.constructor.name);
```

When you run activateEventHandler.jsx, you should see an alert with the text

> Event 'afterNew' with target Document